# Codeception Navbar Helper

Tags: codeception

I want to have the main navigation in a helper. So I can access it from every test but when the html changes I do it only in the helper. In the example of the docs the helper is not there.

http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage

```
<?php
class SignUpCest
{
    /**
     * @var Helper\SignUp
     */
    protected $signUp;

    /**
     * @var Helper\NavBarHelper
     */
    protected $navBar;

    protected function _inject(\Helper\SignUp $signUp, \Helper\NavBar $navBar)
    {
        $this->signUp = $signUp;
        $this->navBar = $navBar;
    }

    public function signUp(\AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('sign up');

        $this->navBar->click('Sign up');
        $this->signUp->register([
            'first_name'            => 'Joe',
            'last_name'             => 'Jones',
            'email'                 => 'joe@jones.com',
            'password'              => '1234',
            'password_confirmation' => '1234'
        ]);
    }
}

?>
```

Is anyone using it?

Comment: Are you looking for documentation of helpers? It is in http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode

Comment: And how looks the \Helper\NavBar? The source code of the example